# AWS AppSync - Creating Resources for schema missing custom types and enums

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I understand that enums are not standard type in Dynamo: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=836386

However, what is the exact resolution here? 
How are we supposed to appropriately represent relations with the generated code?

-- Am I missing something or is the generated code correct and we need to create some custom fields in the dynamo tables and then rewrite the queries?

Example:

```
type Competition {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  creator: UserProfile!
  startDate: String!
  endDate: String!
  competitionType: CompetitionType!
  competitors: [UserProfile]!
  prize: Prize!
}
```

A competition is created by a user, has a type, a prize, and has competitors. When `create resources` for this table, the code is clearly missing any information that is derived out of the custom types or enums. Complex schemas will always have this type of structure, so I'm a bit confused on the outputted code and right direction from here.

```
extend type Mutation {
    createCompetition(input: CreateCompetitionInput!): Competition
}

input CreateCompetitionInput {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  startDate: String!
  endDate: String!
  ## Missing info
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When AppSync generates the schema automatically it skips these as they are intended to be added manually with additional resolvers. You can define a new query that is attached to each of the custom or enum fields, but the data you are referencing will need to be stamped with something that is unique to the competition so that it can be queried on in relation to this type (as dynamoDB isn't a relational db).

When creating a new Competition you will need to update child fields with something unique to that competition. I.e. each UserProfile that needs to be tracked as a competitor gets stamped with this Competitions ID. Mutations for each of the custom fields need to be handled separately.

This article helped me solve this same question: https://keyholesoftware.com/2018/05/17/go-forth-and-appsync/.